# build fail , "'com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree qualid'" error occur

Tags: java, spring-boot, thingsboard, java-12

When I try to run the application it show the error.

[image]

`java: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport does not have member field 'com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree qualid'`

some people said this error relate to `lombok` but i have no idea with error.

I tried to use JDK 11,12,14,21. Error still here.

Environment:

OS: Window 11

ThingsBoard: version 3.6

Browser: chrome

JDK : openjdk 12

springboot:2.7.10

lombok:1.18.18

Comment: where you able to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Brother, you missed jdk 17(go to file and project structure if using IntelliJ) . Try it with this dependency :1.18.24

this should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).